# Ontology design: Individual in Subclass not showing in Super Class?

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, protege, protege4

I just want to clarify as to why an Individual/Member in a subclass doesnt show up as a member in the superclass?

For example

```
Human
   Male
   Female
```

If Male has two members/individuals, namely "John" and "Shawn", shouldn't they show up in the superclass too?

From my understanding, "John" and "Shawn", are male and hence Human

Or should I have to explicitly state something to make that happen

Edit:

Okay, so i just tested something, if I use DL-QUERY to query the superclass, the Individual does in fact show up for the superclass …

This is weird. Is this is a bug?

I'm using Protégé 5.2.

Comment: I think the Protege version is a typo. Version 5 has not been released yet. Was it 4.2?

Comment: Says 5.0 on the new download page, it's beta though... could that be it??

http://protege.stanford.edu/products.php#desktop-protege

Comment: I think the most recent beta released is 5.0 beta 15 (Protege goes through very long beta periods...)

Comment: So is it the beta thats causing this issue or is this expected behaviour

Comment: Can you post a screenshot showing what you mean?  As I recall, the default views in Protege 4.x only show what's explicitly asserted until a reasoner is run, and *then* inferences can be shown.  That x, a member of Y, is a member of Y's superclasses, is something that a reasoner would be needed for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the Protege 5.0b15. In Protege 4.3 both Shawn and John are showing as Members of class Human after running the reasoner. I filed a bug against Protege 5.0.

Comment: Yeap, figured this out after running on a different machine as well